# Angular 7: Taking action if request takes too long

Tags: angular, request, response

So I have a loading icon that displays when the application is interacting with the server.  When the request goes out the icon displays, when the response comes back then remove the icon.  It's fairly straight forward.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.spinnerService.addPendingLoad();

    //We need to add this header to all outbound requests to note this is an XHR request
    const authReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
    });

    return next.handle(authReq).pipe(
      tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if(event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          this.spinnerService.removePendingLoad();
        }
      }));
  }

export class SpinnerService {
  pendingLoads: number = 0;

  constructor(private spinnerService: NgxSpinnerService) {}

  addPendingLoad() {
    this.pendingLoads++;
    this.spinnerService.show();
  }

  removePendingLoad() {
    this.pendingLoads--;
    if(this.pendingLoads <= 0) {
      this.spinnerService.hide();
    }
  }
}
```

So the problem I want to solve is that most of the time the requests will return immediately so what ends up happening is that you get a very fast show/hide of the icon and it can be kind of a jarring experience.

I have tried putting a timeout on the `this.spinnerService.hide();` of maybe 500ms so the loading icon will always be on screen a minimum amount of time.  This is a more pleasing experience but ends making the loading icon display longer than it really has too which can make the application "feel" sluggish.

What I am aiming for is being able to somehow gauge how long the request has been pending for and only display the loading icon if a request is taking an abnormally long time.

So for example, most requests will respond within 100ms or so.  If something happens though that causes the response to be delayed then trigger to loading icon to be displayed only after that 100ms marker.  So if the full request took 300ms then the loading icon would only be shown from 100ms -> 300ms.  If the request takes less than 100ms then no icon needs to be shown.

Is something like this possible?  I do understand edge cases will happen like a request taking 105ms so I will still encounter that jarring experience but IMO it's a trade off to always having a loading icon on screen even if it's not needed.

Comment: "addPendingLoad" can initialize a local variable with the current timestamp. Then compare that timestamp with elapsed time. if that is greater than some threshold then display the spinner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of displaying the spinner right away, you can display it in a `setTimeout` callback:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

  let delayExpired = false;

  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {                   // Set spinner timeout
    delayExpired = true;
    this.spinnerService.addPendingLoad();              // Show spinner after delay
  }, 100);                                             // Wait 100 ms to show spinner

  ...

  return next.handle(authReq).pipe(
    tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);                         // Cancel spinner timeout
        if (delayExpired) {
          this.spinnerService.removePendingLoad();     // Hide spinner
        }
      }
    }));
  }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpxgwl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: Fantastic thanks, I was definitely over thinking it.  So simple!